# Example 5-1 shows about as basic of a program as you can get - what do we need "about"?

Tags: grammar

An excerpt from a book on programming.

> Example 5-1 shows **about** as basic of a program as you can get.

To me, sounds like a weird word choice. Without it, the sentence makes more sense to me.

Comment: It's an *extremely* informal usage. Personally, I would not include ***of*** in this exact context - it sounds more "rustic/uneducated" to me, rather than simply "casual/relaxed". But see [“How big of a problem” vs. “how big a problem”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30011/) on ELU for more on the usage. The word ***about*** here is a perfectly natural usage - again, it's *informal*, but so is the whole construction anyway, so it fits in well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When used as an adverb about can mean "approximately". That is the usage here. About is being used to weaken the statement. The author does not want to firmly state that this particular program is the smallest possible in PHP, but that the program is almost as simple as possible.

Comment: I really don't think ***about*** in OP's example is intended as any kind of weakening "hedge". The usage is effectively facetious, and the author's clear intent is to convey that Ex 5.1 is *exceptionally* basic. It's not really important to either him or the reader that there might be an even more basic alternative - all that matters is the reader should understand that Ex 5.1 is *the very opposite of "complicated"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the insight. I agree that the usage means *exceptionally basic*. I've always thought that the usage was trying to place the item near an extreme without declaring it to be the **most** extreme possible. You are right that most people probably do not consider the veracity of such a claim before speaking and simply mean *exceptional*.

Comment: Yeah - I mean, if you say *"That's [just] about the most stupid thing I ever heard!"*, you don't expect whoever you're haranguing to be thinking *"Thank fuck for that! At least he doesn't think it's **the** most stupid thing he ever heard!"*.

Answer (score 3):

There is a colloquial American idiom that goes like, "That's about as big a truck as you can get." I think this author added "about" in order to make their saying sound like this idiom. You're right that it is a bit awkward. I think the (intended) effect is to add a tone of friendly reassurance that the program really is basic.